# Call a macro every time any method is called - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods

I wrote a debug macro that prints to the console the passed-in string whenever the global `kDebug` flag == `YES`.

I need to print out the name of a method and its class name whenever any method is called.

That works fine when I painstakingly go through every method and write the name of the class and the method in a string.

Is there any special handler that gets called when any method in Objective-C is called, and if so, is there a way that I can somehow override it to call my debug macro?

The entire purpose of this is so that I don't have to go through every method in my code and hand-code the method signature in the debug macro call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for a method logging facility, rather than build your own, one is actually built into the Objective-C runtime.

You might want to read over the Objective-C section of Apple's Technote 2124:
[Technical Note TN2124: Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://web.archive.org/web/20130622041930/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/)

I would also recommend reading over Dave Dribin's blog posting about using the runtime's facility for tracing messages. You can find that here: [Tracing Objective-C messages - Dave Dribin's Blog](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/). Dave notes a `logObjCMessageSend` function that gets called, which you could use to customize your logging behavior. It's a little tricky to use, but Dave gives the info necessary to successfully use it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Dtrace](http://www.1729.us/cocoasamurai/Debugging%20Cocoa%20with%20DTrace.pdf). [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CreatingaCustomInstrument/CreatingaCustomInstrument.html) provides a GUI interface.  You can, say, provide a regex to match all the methods you want to log.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you were looking for the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` macro... but the accepted answer is probably a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code, after asking a similar question here [How can I log names of each called class method in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924225/how-can-i-log-names-of-each-called-class-method-in-objective-c)

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if(aSelector){
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    }
    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
```