# How can I log names of each called class method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

When I want to see the order of the object method calls, I have to put logs each method I implemented like this.

```
- (void)updateTime:(float)time
{
  NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
```

Hence I have to put this code in every method on the class, and it's very boring to insert and delete so many log function calls every time I am debugging a class.

So how can I trigger `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);` in a class on each method call?

Edit:

I ended up with this code. And was not answered anywhere else.

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if(aSelector){
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
    }
    return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}
```

Comment: are u asking for a stacktrace which shows the sequential method calls in a log?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri it sounds like she's asking for her NSLog statement to be automatically placed at the top of every class function without having to write it in; for instance, by some kind of code pre-processing

Comment: @Alex yes. exactly

Comment: See also: [ObjC track all method calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7223555)

Answer (score 1):

You can run your executable with `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled=YES`. You can set this in Xcode Schemes, under Argument Variables under Run.

You end up with output like

```
    + NSObject NSObject initialize
    + NSNotificationCenter NSObject initialize
    + NSNotificationCenter NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter
```

More info [here](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/), and [here](https://www.omnigroup.com/blog/More_objc_method_tracing)

Comment: I ended up with this code
    - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
        if(aSelector){
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(aSelector));
        }
        return [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    }