# ios log a trace of every method call application crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

Tweak gets installed properly; I'm trying to log a trace of every method call for the specified hook.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface logTool: NSObject
+ (void)logDataFromNSString: (NSString *)logContent;
@end

@implementation logTool
+ (void)logDataFromNSString: (NSString *)logContent
{
    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSData *data;

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: @"/tmp/filelog.txt"];

    [file seekToEndOfFile];

    logContent = [logContent stringByAppendingString:@"\n------------\n"];
    data = [logContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [file writeData: data];

    [file closeFile];
}
@end


%hook IGAPIRequestBuilder
+ (id)builderWithHTTPMethod:(unsigned long long)arg1 format:(id)arg2 
    {
        [logTool logDataFromNSString:@">>>> BEGIN - [IGAPIRequestBuilder builderWithHTTPMethod]"];
        id ret = %orig;[logTool logDataFromNSString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ret value: %@", ret]];
        [logTool logDataFromNSString:@"<<<< END - [IGAPIRequestBuilder builderWithHTTPMethod]"];
        return ret; 
    }

%end
```

^ That has been my attempt so far; but my application seems to be crashing the momment I open the app. When I get rid of everything inside %hook IGAPIRequestBuilder it seems to be working properly again.

I'm currently on ios 10.2. The code compiles fine. I can't think of ways to debug the issue so it directs us to something more specific, apologies about that if it's too board.

https://pastebin.com/7vYQ40e0 -- This is the crash report

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223555/objective-c-track-all-method-calls and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783223/call-a-macro-every-time-any-method-is-called-objective-c

Comment: Whatever I did doesn't work, can you please tell me why my application is crashing? I would like to learn why first. @JoshCaswell

Comment: I know nothing about theos or "hooking".